# Delay jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay

Hi guys I don't know why my timing function is not working. Consider the following code...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'conversation.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var conversation = data.conversation1;
            $.each(conversation, function(i, user) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('<li>').attr({
                        class : 'list-group-item',
                    }).text(user.nombre + " : " + user.text).
                    appendTo('#messages');
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I get a json by ajax and I want to show each message by creating time 1 or 2 seconds, it works but just the first time, but after that, all the messages appear at once.

If some one could help me please to understand whats is going on.

Thanks guys I will keep searching. :(

Comment: you are setting a time out of 3 secs for each user in the conversation.  All of the timeouts will expire after 3 seconds (so they will all show up after that, at the same time)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Was my answer able to point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply the timeout delay in your `.each` loop by the iteration count to have it appear as an incremented delay for each message. Observe the following...

```
$.each(conversation, function(i, user) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('<li>').attr({
            class : 'list-group-item',
        })
        .text(user.nombre + " : " + user.text)
        .appendTo('#messages');
    }, 3000 * (i + 1)); // 3000, 6000, 9000 etc.
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/s9u8uvqz/) - simplified demo

Comment: NOte to OP.  The root problem is that your `$.each()` loops runs more or less instantaneously for purpose of this discussion.  You are setting a timeout on each iteration of the loop that is the same value, meaning first item may execute at 3000ms after loop start, second at 3001ms after loop start, third at 3002ms, etc. (here I am generally equating a single loop iteration as taking 1 ms, which is probably slower than actual loop iteration time).

Comment: Yep now I understand but for example how can I do the next. I want a random time the problem is if some number gives me at first iteration 2s, the second iter gives me s1 so the second iteration appears first !! i want the second wait one second (random time) after the last. do I explain myself ?